# Comparing all columns in two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that I need to join together.  Once joined I want to compare 50 different columns and list every row where the columns don't match.  Is there an easier way to solve this than by doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
   INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON 
   TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
WHERE T1.NAME <> T2.NAME 
   OR T1.DESCRIPTION <> T2.DESCRIPTON --48 more comparisons
```

Comment: are the table's identical in regards to column names (and order)? If so, you can use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: No, but if it would help I could create a view for the 2nd table to appear the same as the 1st.

Comment: Creating the view wouldn't save you any extra keystrokes from just adding the 48 other comparisons i wouldn't think. Maybe someone has a crafty way. Are you just trying to mitigate keystrokes or is this performing terribly given all the predicates?

Comment: I am just trying save keystrokes now and prevent someone from forgetting to add any new fields to the comparison section in the future.

Comment: extra comparisons would only happen when new columns are added (DDL changes) in which you'd have to update your view as well. I don't have a good way unfortunately.

Comment: IMHO, If you have two tables with 50 columns that should match, something smells funny in your database design, and I don't mean ha-ha funny.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant way to do this but you could compare the table schemas to one another and inner-join on the column names to generate a list of columns shared by both tables.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.COLUMN_NAME FROM [Database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Table1
INNER JOIN [Database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Table2 
ON Table1.COLUMN_NAME = Table2.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE Table1.TABLE_NAME = N'Table1' AND Table2.TABLE_NAME = N'Table2'
```

Then write a dynamic query that uses that list of column names for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION.

```
--sample tables
WITH tb1 as
    (select 111 as id, 1 as a, 2 as b union all select 112 as id, 3 as a, 4 as b),

    tb2 as
    (select 111 as id, 1 as a, 2 as b union all select 112 as id, 3 as a, 5 as b),
  --  
    tablesunion as 

    (select * from tb1 union
    select * from tb2),
    tableseq as
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS SEQ,
            *
     FROM tablesunion)
    SELECT tb1.*, tb2.*
    FROM   tableseq s
    inner join tb1
    on (s.id = tb1.id)
    inner join tb2
    on (s.id = tb2.id)
    WHERE  seq > 1;
```

The result would be:

```
id  a   b   id  a   b
112 3   4   112 3   5
```